# What happens in TFS when merging 2 different branches where same file is modified in 2 branches.

Tags: tfs, merge, tfvc

1. There is Main branch
2. I created a new branch from Main called 'PBI'
3. There is a file called 'publisher' which is modified in Main and it is also modified in 'PBI'
4. I want to make sure all the changes in Main are reflected in PBI, so I decided to merge main onto PBI so that PBI is upto date with Main.

When I did the merge, in pending changes it showed publisher[merge]

So what happens now when I checkin the pending change which is publisher[merge]

1. My changes for 'publisher' in PBI remain? ; *If this happens it is a disaster, whats the point of merge*
2. The new changes in Main overwrite the content in PBI branch for 'publisher'; *If this happens, it is a disaster too*
3. A conflict arises and I need to choose which one remains. *This makes sense*

Comment: Are you talking about Git or TFVC?

Comment: I am talking about TFVC. You can tell me what happens in Git if you dont know about TFVC

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: There is no documentation on this. TFVC is the worst.

Comment: How to stop auto resolution in TFVC eclipse?

Comment: No documentation? Google "tfvc merging". Third result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/merge-folders-files. Google "tfvc conflicts". First result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts

Comment: There is no documentation of how auto-resolution of conflicts occur. It is a major disaster. In the name of auto-resolution , it just keeps my version which is exactly not what I want.

Comment: Without more specific information on the scenario that you're encountering, it's impossible to give a better answer than to point you to the documentation. The scenarios in which automatic conflict resolution can be applied are explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts#understand-the-automatic-options

Answer (score 0):

Just as Daniel mentioned, you need to check the documents first:

[Resolve Team Foundation Version Control conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/resolve-team-foundation-version-control-conflicts#resolve-conflicts)

Then try to set AutoMerge.

By default, VS will popup the `Resolve conflicts` dialog when have conflicts during the mergering. You can select the merger action to merger the conflicts manually.

You can also have a try for the Auto Merge extension:

- [Auto Merge for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KulikovDenis.AutoMergeforVisualStudio2017)
- [Auto Merge for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KulikovDenis.AutoMergeforVisualStudio2015)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Depends. Git can auto-merge most of the time, meaning you'll keep the changes for both. When Git can't figure out how to auto-merge your changes (For example, if both branches modified the same line when compared), then a merge conflict will arise, and you'll have to go in there manually and resolve it

Comment: "Git can auto-merge most of the time, meaning you'll keep the changes for both". What do you mean keep the changes for both?  I merging to make sure my dev branch is uptodate with Main branch.

Comment: All right, suppose you have the file data.txt
`data 1
data 2`
On commit A, which is shared by Main and Dev
Then on Dev, you modify it to
`data 1
data 2
data 3`
And on main, you modify it to
`data 1
data 2
data 4`
Then when you merge main into dev, you get
`data 1
data 2
data 3
data 4`
So your Dev branch is "updated" with Main branch in the sense that it contains all of the changes made in Main
(Pretend those 'data' are on different lines, stackoverflow doesn't let me do multi-line comments)

Comment: None of this happens in TFVC. It just takes my version and goes along. It completely neglects the Main branch code. According to your example, after merge my code will be data 1 data 2 data 3 because that is the code on my dev. It just keeps it that way.

Comment: Hmm, maybe TFVC works differently than git, though it doesn't make much sense